# Is there an animation that does a pulsating effect?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, animation, uiimage

I need to make an image that does a pulsating effect (fading in and out). I have another way to accomplish this with NSArray of images, but if there is an easier way that someone can point to me I will appreciate it. I do not want to make too many images.

Comment: what is pulsating effect ?? Any example

Comment: how about using a UIAnimation and animating the alpha and the shadow of the image?  That might get you close without having to create any more images.

Comment: Define “pulsating”. Fading in and out? Growing larger and smaller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no pulse animation. What you want to do is:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                  animation:^{
                      // Fade In
                  }
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                      [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                                       animation:^{
                                           // Fade Out
                                       }
                 }];
```

Repeat as necessary.

Comment: Wrap that in a function, call that function in the fade out completion, and keep a counter if you need to do a certain number of animations.